# Does it make sense to use static masks to improve the quality of a zero-shot source separation model

Tags: fine-tuning, audio-processing

I'm thinking about ways to fine-tune a neural network for source separation, specifically [AudioSep](https://audio-agi.github.io/Separate-Anything-You-Describe/AudioSep_arXiv.pdf)

It is known that in nlp tasks, RAG is often used as an alternative to fine tuning to provide LLM with unknown context.

I wonder if it is possible to apply the same approach to my neural network?

For example, given a database of masks of an unknown sound and a mask obtained from u-net, could I somehow improve the output of u-net by using the most similar mask from the mask database for the class being separated?